# Rename capture devices with C#, is it possible?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, input-devices

Can I rename the capture devices with C#?

Something like this:

[image: Original Name]

to

[image: Ranamed]

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't implement this functionality with C#, because you can only enumerate the devices that will fetch the information about all in for each loop, but you cant rename it.

Read this msdn article on friendly name: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd316587(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Can you elaborate your answer? please

Comment: you can only enumerate the devices that will fetch the information about all in for each loop, but you cant rename it.

Comment: @DeshDeepSingh That's not an elaboration. We're looking for a citation, a source of reference, an explanation about the lack of functionality, your personal experiences, or something like that. As it stands, your answer looks like a guess, or from having glanced at documentation.